# Add zero value to one row in R using tidyverse (wide format table)

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to add `0` numbers to one row in a wideformat table based on 2 columns by using `tidyverse`.

My example is:

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("a" , "b", "c"),
                 id2 = c("a", "a", "d"),
                 n1 = c(2,2,0),
                 n2 = c(2,1,1),
                 n3 = c(0,1,1),
                 n4 = c(0,1,1))
```

I would like to say that if the `id1` == `b` and `id2` == `a`, the entire second row of the table would be added with `0` number, except for the column `n3`.

My desire output:

```
id1 id2 n1 n2 n3 n4
a    a   2  2  0 0   
b    a   0  0  1 0
b    d   0  1  1 1
```

I can do with base R, but I am trying to do with the package `tidyverse`.
Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example

Comment: *In general*, the tidyverse solution to such a question is: (1) transform the table into long format; (2) perform the (now trivial) operation; (3) if necessary, transform back into wide format. This workflow is *literally* in the name: that’s what “tidy” refers to.

Comment: @Sotos I alrady added.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, I think it is such a easier if I tranform the wide format to the long format, but I still want to do with the wide format, since I am dealing with the name of the species. I realized that it is quite hard for me to check the name with the long format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer` and then `pivot_wider`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 3:6) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(id1 == "b" &
                          id2 == "a" & name != "n3", 0, value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  id1   id2      n1    n2    n3    n4
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     a         2     2     0     0
2 b     a         0     0     1     0
3 c     d         0     1     1     1
```

Edit: To keep the data "wide":

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(-c(id1,id2,n3),
                ~ifelse(id1 == "b" & id2 == "a",
                        0,
                        .)
                )
         )
```

Comment: Thank you alot, whether you can try with the wide format table, since I am trying to do with that.